# Script Saving the folders names in a text file?

Tags: scripting

I have a list of foldes in a parent folders how can I save all the folders names in one text file? as the following

```
Parent folder 
|...A (folder)
|...B (folder)
|...C (folder)
|...D (folder)
|...E (folder)
|...F (folder)
```

I want to save all the folders names in a text file and save it in the parent folder

```
parent folder 
|...A (folder)
|...B (folder)
|...C (folder)
|...D (folder)
|...E (folder)
|...F (folder)
|...text file contain the names of the folders i.e if I open the file I will find the folders names (A,B,C,D,E,F)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try any one of these commands from the Parent folder.

If you need to find all the files,

```
find . -print > list_of_files
```

If you just need the directories and the sub-directories inside them as well,

```
find . -type d > list_of_files
```

If you just need directories for single level,

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d > list_of_files
```

Now, with `maxdepth 1` option, we are asking to check for directories only in the current level. For example,

**Parent Folder**

```
pwd
/test
```

**Directories in my Parent Folder**

```
ls
folder1  folder2  folder3  folder4
```

Now, inside `folder1` directory I create 2 more directories named *folder1_1* and *folder1_2*.

Now, this is the output of `find . -type d`.

```
find . -type d
.
./folder4
./folder2
./folder3
./folder1
./folder1/folder1_2
./folder1/folder1_1
```

However, if I specify `maxdepth 1` option, I will get the output as,

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d
.
./folder4
./folder2
./folder3
./folder1
```

As you could see, the sub dirs inside the directory are not listed.

Quoting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2596736/1742825), you could use your `find` as below to remove the leading **./** in your command output.

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%P\n'
```

Comment: @ Ramesh. kindly what is the meaning of 1 (after the flag maxdepth) in the third command line?

Comment: @MJA, please see the updated answer.

Comment: @ Ramesh. How can we remove the "./" from the output of this command line?

Comment: @MJA, see updated.